# Windows XP installation failure, blue screen white text, stop error screen

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-installation, bluescreenview

512GB hard drive is functional and formatted NTFS.

8GB of RAM tested ok too.

Used genuine Microsoft installation CD.

BIOS version: F.12

BIOS vendor:  Insyde

2012 HP Pavilion dv6

CPU: Intel Core i7-2670QM

CPU @ 2.20 GHz

Can anyone help me decipher the following:

"A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.

If this is the first time you have seen this stop error screen, restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check to be sure you have adequate disk space. If a driver is identified in the stop message, disable the driver or check with the manufacturer for driver updates. Try changing video adapters.

Check with your hardware vendor for any BIOS updates. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing. If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then select Safe Mode.

Technical information:
***  STOP: 0x0000007E (0xc0000005, 0xF73D1466, 0xF78D5ED4, 0xF78D5BD4)

***  acpi.sys - Address F73D1466 base at F73C6000, Datestamp 3d6dd69f  "

Comment: I'm guessing, but I wonder if the laptop is too modern for run it. XP's about a half decade or more too old

Comment: Given your machine's vintage I'm guessing it most likely has a SATA hard drive, have you looked in the BIOS for a "SATA mode" option, and if so have you tried setting it to "legacy"?

Comment: I tried again.  This time with Ubuntu 22.04 pre-installed on the hard drive and got the following error:                       "Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
US5,307,459  US5,434,872  US5,732,094  US6,570,884  US6,115,776 and US6,327,625

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.38 (12/24/10)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.  No bootable device  -- insert boot disk and press any key"

Answer (score 5):

XP will not run on your machine (2012 HP with CPU that exceeds XP).

It simply will not ever work natively on that machine or anything new(ish).

Load up a Virtual Machine App of your choice. I use VMware Workstation. Then run XP as  Virtual Machine.

This will work - I have it running

Answer (score 3):

The STOP 0x0000007E error means that some software has failed.
The 0xc0000005 further identifies the error as a memory access violation.

As this happens on the installation, it means only that the XP installation
does not support your computer. It probably needs drivers for your
modern hardware that it doesn't have. Given that XP is about two decades
old and is no longer supported by modern manufacturers, there is no
chance of finding XP drivers on the websites of the manufacturers.

In short, you can't install XP on this computer.

Answer (score 2):

Most 0x7e errors I have encounter means the OS doesn't have the drivers necessary to access the hard drive.

Given how old XP is suspect there are no XP compatible drivers for your motherboards disk controller.

This makes installing XP either impossible, or so hard it is not worth doing.